# Incorrect result when using TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime() to get a localised datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I have a very simple task and `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime()` is giving an incorrect result. I simply want to find the current datetime in the "Cen. Australia Standard Time" zone:

```
string timeZone = "Cen. Australia Standard Time";
TimeZoneInfo zoneID = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZone);
DateTime nowAtTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, zoneID);
// result:           24/10/2018 7:43:29 PM
// actual ACST time: 24/10/2018 6:43:29 PM (this is what I want)
// actual ACDT time: 24/10/2018 7:43:29 PM (this is not what I want)
```

I got the actual ACST time from here: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/acst

And the actual ACDT time from here: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/acdt

Note that replacing `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime()` with `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc()` gives identical results.

Note that the timezone is entered by the customer and this is all the information I have available. They do not record the city.

The result from `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime()` appears to be giving ACDT time, even though I have specified ACST.

The problem could be that `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime()` is applying daylight savings to ACST, when it should not be? If so how can I prevent it from doing that?

Comment: Your code is correct for Adelaide, which does use DST.  Did you mean Darwin (which doesn't)?

Comment: Darwin would be `"AUS Central Standard Time"`.   (yes, the naming is awful)

Comment: Adelaide does not use ACST though - it uses ACDT. at least so google tells me.

Comment: Adelaide *alternates* between ACST and ACDT. Reference here: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/australia/adelaide.  Darwin is on ACST the whole year: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/australia/darwin

Comment: I'm not after the time in Adelaide. I'm after ACST time.

Comment: For what location?

Comment: the specific location is unknown. I have updated the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time zones in Australia are complex as they are in many parts if the world.  [Wikipedia's page on this subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Australia) is a good overview.

As you can see, there are two major areas that use Australia Central Standard Time.  One uses DST, the other does not.

For .NET on Windows with the `TimeZoneInfo` class:

- Use `"Cen. Australia Standard Time"` for the ID of the south central Australian time zone that uses daylight saving time.  Locations include Adelaide, and others.
- Use `"AUS Central Standard Time"` for the ID of the north central Australian time zone that does not use daylight saving time.  Locations include Darwin, and others.

The `TimeZoneInfo` class is doing the correct thing, based on the time zone it is given.

As far as picking the correct zone, use `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()` to return all of the available time zones, the use the `Id` and `DisplayName` properties to create a drop-down list.  The user should only have to choose from the display names, and you only need to use the ID in your code.

Comment: Great thanks! Btw, how do you know that `Cen. Australia Standard Time` includes adelaide, but `AUS Central Standard Time` includes Darwin? This is correct, but do you have a link on that so I can use it for other timezones? It wasn't in wikipedia. Googling `Cen. Australia Standard Time` was what originally led me in the wrong direction since google responds with `ACST`, which is not technically correct (it should respond with `ACDT`).

Comment: Examine the results from `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()` as I explained in the post.  Notice the display names have these cities in them.  There are also a variety of other ways to view this data, such as with `TZUtil.exe /L` on the command line, or by digging through the Windows registry.

Comment: OK cheers. You didn't say that is what `DisplayName` gives in the post.

Answer (score -1):

You need to call `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(datetime, timezoneInfo)`. Check this

```
 string timeZone = "Cen. Australia Standard Time";
            TimeZoneInfo zoneID = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZone);            
            DateTime nowAtTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, zoneID);
```

Comment: That is equivalent to what was in the question. `ConvertTimeFromUtc` and `ConvertTime` behave the same when passed `DateTime.UtcNow`, due to the way `DateTimeKind` works.

Comment: yep. i have confirmed that they give identical results - not what i am after.